# Email content Only Showing 2 lines Since Kitkat 4.4 Update

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, stock-email-app

Since the Kitkat update to my partners Nexus 4 the default email client only shows the first 2 lines of any email message. Also that text is shown above the email header which seems a bit weird.

It worked fine before the update with the default email client & we could see the entire text.

How do I fix this?

Edit: I have tried clearing the cache and the data but this does not fix the issue.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the error in my Nexus 4 with the default email app (IMAP) but I cannot. I can see all emails correctly with all its content (for example the Android Enthusiasts Weekly Newsletter). Can you attach screen captures of the problem?